# Finding components of a shape inside a circle.

Tags: geometry

I'm just working on some summer problems so that I can be more prepared when I go into my class in the fall. I found a website full of problems of the content we will be learning but it doesn't have the answers. I need a little guidance on how to do this problem.
Here is the problem:

The diagram shows a circle of radius 8 metres. The points ABCD lie on the circumference of the circle.
[image: picture of this diagram]

BC = 14 m, CD = 11.5 m, AD = 8 m, $\angle ADC$ = 104°, and $\angle BCD$ = 73°.

a. Find AC.
AC is the diameter, right? So you would have double the radius which is 8 metres. So AC = 16?

b. (i) Find $\angle ACD$
    (ii) Hence, find $\angle ACB$
If angle C is 73°, would ACD be half of that?
And then ACB is the other half?

c. Find the area of triangle ADC.
I believe the area of the triangle is 1/2 x base x height. So, 1/2 x 8 x 11.5?

d. Hence or otherwise, find the total area of the shaded regions.
This is confusing and I do not know how to do this part.

Comment: AC is not the diameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IMPORTANT: The angle subtended by the diameter on the circumference of a circle is always $90^\circ$

Since $\angle ACD$ subtend $104^\circ$, AC is NOT a diameter.

Use Cosine rule to find AC
$$AC^2=AD^2+DC^2-2AD\cdot DC\cdot\cos104^\circ$$
$$AC^2=8^2+11.5^2-2\times8\times11.5\times(-0.241)$$
$$ AC=15.51m$$

Then use Sine rule to find $\angle ACD$
$$\frac{\sin{\angle ACD}}{8}=\frac{\sin{\angle ADC}}{AC}$$
$$\frac{\sin{\angle ACD}}{8}=\frac{\sin{\angle 104}}{15.51}$$
$$sin\angle ACD=0.5$$
$$\angle ACD=30^\circ$$
So $\angle ACB=73^\circ-30^\circ=43^\circ$

Best way to find  $\triangle ADC  $ area is to choose $AC$ as the base then find height using $DC\cdot\sin\angle ACD$ (i.e perpendicular distance from D to side AC)

Area of $\triangle ADC=\frac12\times AC\times11.5\times \sin30 =44.59m^2$

Similarly, find Area of $\triangle ABC$,

$$\triangle ABC= \frac12\times AC\times BC\times \sin \angle ACB$$
$$= \frac12\times 15.51\times 14\times \sin43^\circ$$
$$= 74.18m^2$$

Shaded Area=$ \pi\times8^2-(\triangle ABC +\triangle ADC)$